# Error while installing package: installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dpkg, python3

(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

> Unable to install "Time Table calculator":
>
> Error while installing package: installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status4

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: kindly check this i had same issue earlier:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162377/syntaxerror-while-setting-up-python3-aptdaemon/1162382?noredirect=1#comment1940771_1162382

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt update` first and then `sudo apt upgrade`. Then try to installing the Python-related package again.

Comment: Nope. `sudo apt upgrade` returns the exact same error listed above. Not a solution.