# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after entering password

Tags: 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and faced an unclean shutdown. After that, I am unable to login. After entering the password, the screen freezes. I am unable to move the mouse cursor. I can enter tty but not sure how to troubleshoot.

Can someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Update:

If I do `journalctl -f` from tty

I can see a syntax error in a Python command. Not sure if that's related

It's in file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py`

```
async = reply_handler and error_handler

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Update:

Did a release upgrade to 20.04 but still no luck. Now it is stuck on login screen with message "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress". Pressing Ctrl+C does not do anything and I am not even able to enter tty now. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 just shows a blinking cursor and no tty

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in tty.

Comment: I followed this post to change the default Python3 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162377/syntaxerror-while-setting-up-python3-aptdaemon

After that I ran the command you shared but there is no output for that

Comment: Trying a `do-release-upgrade` in hopes that I can get my system working again

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a corrupted `xorg.conf` file. Here is how I fixed it

On the GRUB screen, I chose the recovery mode option. Then chose the root prompt

Once logged in as root, I moved the old `xorg.conf` file

```
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
```

After rebooting, it worked fine.